# Changing the hostname of a debian server using a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, web-server

I own a domain name `mydomain.example`, which I use CloudFlare for DNS. The domain is configured to point to my website hosted on GitHub.

In parallel, I have a Debian VPS from OVH, and I would like associate to it a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) (instead of `vps123456.ovh.net`), which I would like to be `subdomain.mydomain.example`.

My long-term plan is to host my website (`mydomain.example`) on this VPS as well, but for now to avoid messing things up, I would like to keep the website unchanged.

After some research using Google, I came up with the following steps:

1. Create an A record in CloudFlare to point `subdomain.mydomain.example` to the IP address `192.0.2.91` of the VPS.
2. Change the hostname of the VPS into `subdomain.mydomain.example`:

   1. Change the content of `/etc/hostname` from `vps123456.ovh.net` to `subdomain.mydomain.example`.
   2. Change the content of `/etc/hosts` from

      ```
      127.0.0.1   localhost
      192.0.2.91  vps123456.ovh.net   vps123456
      ```

      to

      ```
      127.0.0.1   localhost
      192.0.2.91  subdomain.mydomain.example  subdomain
      ```
   3. Apply the change without rebooting:

      ```
      /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start
      ```

After this, when doing `hostname` I obtained `subdomain.mydomain.example`, which is good. But when I opened a new terminal and try `ssh user@subdomain.mydomain.example`, it didn't work (timeout).

**Update:** To clarify, my final goal is not exactly to be able to SSH to the machine using `ssh user@subdomain.mydomain.example`, but rather to associate the IP address of the machine with a FQDN (which is needed for some paperwork: I have to connect to some institutional server through a machine, and for security reason, the IP address of this gateway machine must be associated to a FQDN. I am trying to set my VPS up for that purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare might take some (short) time to distribute your new `A` record to its `DNS` servers. Moreover the old `A` record for `subdomain.domain.example` (or its previous absence) might still be in the cache of the `DNS` recursive resolvers you use, for the amount of time indicated by the `TTL` of the old record (or the last number in the `SOA` record if it didn't exist before). Check with `dig subdomain.domain.example` to see if the IP address is already correct.

However you probably need the reverse lookup for your IP address to return your domain name (check with `dig -x 192.0.2.91`). This is done by adding a `PTR` record by the IP address owner (OVH). Usually you can change your reverse lookup through some web interface.

The line you added to `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.0.2.91  subdomain.mydomain.example  subdomain
```

**locally** (on your machine) functions as three `DNS` records:

```
subdomain.mydomain.example. IN A 192.0.2.91
subdomain.                  IN A 192.0.2.91
91.2.0.191.in-addr.arpa.    IN PTR subdomain.mydomain.example.
```

Now you need the real `PTR` record.

Comment: 1/2 Thank you very much for your answer! Very helpful indeed! I have just found the option in my OVH control panel to set the reverse DNS. Now when doing `dig -x 192.0.2.91`, it shows `91.2.0.191.in-addr.arpa.    IN PTR subdomain.mydomain.example`. Just one thing I am not able to understand: you said that the line `192.0.2.91  subdomain.mydomain.example  subdomain` functions as the above three DNS. However, my current `/etc/hosts` contains `192.0.2.91  vps123456.ovh.net   vps123456` (I reverted the changes I made to make the server accessible again, so currently this file is the original one)

Comment: 2/2 Doesn't that mean we should have the above 3 DNS records for `vps123456`? To make it clearer: why doesn't the `/etc/hosts` have any effects on the DNSs now?

Comment: `/etc/hosts` overrides `DNS` on the machine where it is defined. Apart from `dig`, which is specialized in `DNS`, most programs will resolve domain names and addresses using the C library (cf. [nsswitch.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)). You can run `getent hosts 192.0.2.91` and `getent hosts vps123456` on the server and your desktop to check it. About the `subdomain.` entry: it can not be set in `DNS` since it is a top level domain, but in `/etc/hosts` it is very useful.

Comment: Woah, I understand now. Excellent answers! Thank you so much again for your help!